# Add background into JPANEL in JAVA Eclipse

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I tried to add background image from internet into my `JPanel`, but there is source only for add `JFrame` background and don't have any source for add `JPanel` background. Please Help.

I tried the Image `image= ImageIO.read(new File("resources/2.png"));` also but still failed.

My Jpanel Code:

```
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(32, 178, 170));
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Jlabel` and add image to it. Something like this :

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/yourImage.jpg")));
```

And add label to your panel.